# Javascript stops after 30 seconds on Firefox on Android

Tags: javascript, android, firefox

I have a Javascript script in a web page that needs to run for a few minutes. It runs successfully on Firefox, Chrome and Edge browsers on Windows 10, and on Chrome browser on Android.

However, it always stops after 30 seconds on Firefox on Android (on the same phone that successfully runs the script on Chrome)

Is there a setting on Firefox, or within the script that will allow the script to run for longer than 30 seconds?

Version info: Mozilla/5.0 (Android 9; Mobile; rv:109.0) Gecko/112.0 Firefox/112.0

Comment: [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) might help ..? Blocking UI for minutes is really bad UX.

Comment: In fact the production app uses a web worker, but I knocked up a simple html page containing a script to do some performance testing of various options of modular multiplication, which only runs for 30 sec on Firefox Android.